# Move single user Time Machine backup drive to OS X Server

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, backup, osx-server

I have an external hard drive which is currently used as a Time Machine backup drive for a single machine.  I'd like to move the drive to my Server machine and use it for network backups for all my machines. Can I move the drive and then have the original Mac see its old backup when it connects via the Server?

The Server machine is running Yosemite; the other machines are running Mavericks.